Run remote Debug success,But restart Debug errorInfo-show: connect ECONNREFUSED ip-address:5678
Environment data

OS: Ubuntu 22.04
Python version (& distribution if applicable, e.g. Anaconda): 3.8.10
debugpy version:1.8.1
Using VS Code or Visual Studio: VSCode 1.88.1, Terminal

Actual behavior
I can connect normally with debugging and debugging normally，But click to re -debug, you will prompt an error and exit the debugging

error: connect ECONNREFUSED ip-address:5678

Steps to reproduce:
vscode:
launch.json:
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "connect to remote server",
            "type": "debugpy",
            "request": "attach",
            "preLaunchTask": "Run_Python",
            "connect": {
                "host": "ip-address",
                "port": 5678
            },
            "pathMappings": [
                {
                    "localRoot": "${workspaceFolder}",
                    "remoteRoot": "/home/xxx/py/py/"
                }
            ],
            "justMyCode": true
        }
    ]
}

task.json:
{
    "version": "2.0.0",
    "tasks": [
        {
            "label": "Run_Python",
            "type": "shell",
            "command": "ssh -tt xxx@ip-address 'python /home/xxx/py/py/main.py'",
            "args": [],
            "isBackground": true,
            "group": {
                "kind": "build",
                "isDefault": true
            },
            "problemMatcher": {
                "owner": "python",
                "source": "debugpy",
                "fileLocation": [
                    "relative",
                    "${workspaceFolder}"
                ],
                "pattern": [
                    {
                        "regexp": "\\s+(.*)$",
                        "message": 1
                    },
                    {
                        "regexp": "Connection to closed",
                        "file": 1,
                        "line": 1,
                        "column": 1
                    }
                ],
                "background": {
                    "activeOnStart": false,
                    "beginsPattern": {
                        "regexp": "start"
                    },
                    "endsPattern": {
                        "regexp": "Waiting for debugger attach"
                    }
                }
            },
            "presentation": {
                "echo": true,
                "panel": "shared",
                "focus": true,
                "clear": true
            }
        }
    ]
}

code:
print("start")
import debugpy

# 5678 is the default attach port in the VS Code debug configurations. Unless a host and port are specified, host defaults to 127.0.0.1
debugpy.listen(('0.0.0.0', 5678))
print("Waiting for debugger attach")
debugpy.wait_for_client()
debugpy.breakpoint()
def add_fun(a, b):
    a = a * 10
    b = b * 100
    c = a + b
    return c

if __name__ == '__main__':
    a = 10
    b = 78
    c = add_fun(a, b)
    c = c
    print(f"a + b = {c}")

If I click to restart the debugging, I should continue the normal debugging process

Can this page help?
